# get message and result of rule which implemented the validationRule

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Laravel in new versions marks the `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule` contract as deprecated and suggests the `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule` contract instead

I have a rule like this

```php
class NotNumberRule implements ValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  \Closure(string): \Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString  $fail
     * @return void
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $fail('error');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and I have some settings which have some rules and in my codes, I called the rules in the loop like this:

```php
                foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                    $rule = new ($rule);

                    if ($rule instanceof ValidationRule) {
                    // I don't know how to get result of rule and the message of rule
                    }

                    if (
                        $rule instanceof Rule &&
                        !$rule->passes($setting->field, $value)
                    ) {
                        throw ValidationException::withMessages([$setting->field => $rule->message()]);
                    }
                }
```

in this new laravel implementation I don't know how to get the result and message of the rule?